# Why should we store data in Session using Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session

Can anybody explain the advantages and disadvantages of storing the session data in database while using codeigniter.

I know the differences b/s CI session and native php session.
But my question is to only know

Are there some advantages of storing the session data into database.(because its an optional feature.)
if so then kindly list some of them.

Comment: See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663583/which-session-library-should-i-use-with-codeigniter

Comment: @sitilge CI session does not use the php native session it uses the cookie to store the encrypted data about user or whatever you want to store in CI session